# Get Specific values From Db Column in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I intend to pass the "prices" value of a DB dynamically in my controller, but instead, end up with an array with all the prices. I would love for each button in my view to have a specific price thats from the database

`myview.blade.php`

```
 @foreach ($hotspot_plans as $hotspot_plan)
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="pricing-plan box-shadow color_style1">
                        <div class="plan-name">
                            <h3>
                                {{$hotspot_plan->duration}}
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="price-wrap ">
                            <span class="plan-sign">Ksh</span>
                            <span class="plan-price">{{$hotspot_plan->price}}</span>
                            <span class="plan-decimals">.00</span>
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="plan-button">
                            <a href="/stk/push/simulation" class="btn btn-maincolor">Browse Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

`mycontroller.blade.php`

```
public function stkSimulation()
 {

//         
// }
     $price=HotSpotPlan::all('price');

   dd($price);

}
```

[image: results of dd($price)]

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. From you controller you have passsed the price variable. So you should loop over price. In controller it should be like this.

```
 $prices =HotSpotPlan::all('price');
 
return view('myview.blade.php', [
'prices' => $prices
]);
```

In view

```
@foreach($prices as $price) 
      <div class="price-wrap ">
                            <span class="plan-sign">Ksh</span>
                            <span class="plan-price">{{$price}}</span>
                            <span class="plan-decimals">.00</span>
                            
                        </div>
@endforeach
```